# OracleType for a pl/sql function with a boolean return value?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, return-value

I'm developing this app where I have to call a function written in PL/SQL that returns a boolean. As I understand, bool is not a type in SQL, but in PL/SQL, so what will the return type for the function be?

command.Parameters.Add("P_RETURN", OracleType.???);

(For the record: I have no control over the PL/SQL end of things, so I am not able to rewrite the function)

Answer (score 4):

You could call the `SYS.diutil.bool_to_int` function with the result of calling your function. For example:

```
SYS.diutil.bool_to_int(your_function(...))
```

From the documentation:

> `bool_to_int`:  translates 3-valued BOOLEAN TO NUMBER FOR USE
>       IN sending BOOLEAN parameter / RETURN VALUES
>       BETWEEN pls v1 (client) AND pls v2. since sqlnet
>       has no BOOLEAN bind variable TYPE, we encode
>       booleans AS false = 0, true = 1, NULL = NULL FOR
>       network transfer AS NUMBER

Comment: It's new to me too. http://www.psoug.org/reference/diutil.html
Apparently a package of utilities for DIANA (PL/SQL compiler). It's not officially documented but it seems to be stable from 7.3.4 through to 11g.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the PL/SQL only BOOLEAN type to a SQL supported type. I know, this is painful : welcome to the Oracle world. [Here is Steven Feuerstein reusable way to deal with it](http://htmldb.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=2853:4:4863128548814396::NO::P4_QA_ID:225).

As a side note, [BOOLEANs are considered useless in SQL](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6263249199595) (by Oracle anyway).